# Conway's game of life in C++ with SDL

Tags: c++, game-of-life, sdl

This is my attempt at a basic implementation of GOL. The user can add and remove cells with the mouse and some basic stats are printed to console. Any feedback is welcome, but I have a couple of specific questions:

- In  `Cell::get_neighbours()` it seems a bit inefficient to keep constructing vectors for each cell. In Python I would use `yield` to avoid this; is there anything comparable in C++?
- In `InputHandler::get_input` I just call three 'subfunctions' which aren't reused anywhere else. Is this good practice or is one long function better?

[image: A screenshot of the program running]

Below is the code in rough order of importance; alternatively [here](https://github.com/andrewhickman/gameoflife) is a github link.

`main.cpp` is the main loop for the program; including a framerate cap:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "graphics.h"
#include "input.h"
#include "logic.h"

const int TARGET_FRAMERATE = 60;
const int TARGET_TICKRATE = 2;
const int FRAMES_PER_TICK = TARGET_FRAMERATE / TARGET_TICKRATE;
const int TARGET_TIMESTEP = 1000 / TARGET_FRAMERATE;

int main() {
    Graphics graphics;
    InputHandler input_handler;
    Gamestate gamestate;

    unsigned int timestep, time0, time1 = 0;
    unsigned int frame_count = 0;
    while (!input_handler.quit) {
        // Get time
        time0 = time1;
        time1 = SDL_GetTicks();
        timestep = time1 - time0;
        frame_count++;
        // Main game loop
        if (frame_count % FRAMES_PER_TICK == 0) {
            gamestate.update();
        }
        input_handler.get_input(gamestate);
        graphics.render(gamestate, input_handler);
        // FPS cap
        if (timestep < TARGET_TIMESTEP) {
            SDL_Delay(TARGET_TIMESTEP - timestep);
            time1 += TARGET_TIMESTEP - timestep;
        }
    }
    printf("Exiting game\n");
}
```

The rules and implementation of the game are in `logic.cpp` and its header. I tried to keep this independent of SDL and the UI portions of the code:

**logic.h**

```
#ifndef _logic_h_included_
#define _logic_h_included_

#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

struct Cell {
    int x, y;

    bool operator==(const Cell&) const;
    std::vector<Cell> get_neighbours() const;
};

struct Hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Cell&) const;
};

class Gamestate {
public:
    Gamestate();

    std::unordered_set<Cell, Hash> board;    // The set of live cells
    bool paused;
    int generation;

    void update();
};

#endif
```

**logic.cpp**

```
#include "logic.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>

Gamestate::Gamestate() :
    paused(true),
    generation(0) {}

void Gamestate::update() {
    if (paused) {
        return;
    }
    std::unordered_map<Cell, int, Hash> num_neighbours;
    // Count neighbours of each cell
    for (Cell c : board) {
        for (Cell n : c.get_neighbours()) {
            if (!num_neighbours.count(n)) {
                num_neighbours.emplace(n, 0);
            }
            ++num_neighbours[n];    // Note each cell counts itself as a neighbour
        }
    }
    // Apply the iteration rule
    for (auto pair : num_neighbours) {
        Cell c;
        int n;
        std::tie(c, n) = pair;
        if (n == 3) {    // i.e. c is live and has 2 neighbours or is dead and has 3
            board.insert(c);
        } else if (board.count(c) and n != 4) {
            board.erase(c);
        }
    }
    ++generation;
    printf("Generation: %d, Total cells: %lu\n", generation, board.size());
}

bool Cell::operator==(const Cell& other) const {
    return (x == other.x) and (y == other.y);
}

std::vector<Cell> Cell::get_neighbours() const {
    std::vector<Cell> neighbours;
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; ++dx) {
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; ++dy) {
            neighbours.push_back({x + dx, y + dy});
        }
    }
    return neighbours;
}

std::size_t Hash::operator()(const Cell& c) const {
    return c.x * 31 + c.y;
}
```

Everything to do with getting user input is in `input.cpp` and its header:

**input.h**

```
#ifndef _input_h_included_
#define _input_h_included_

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "logic.h"

const int WINDOW_SIZE_X = 600;
const int WINDOW_SIZE_Y = 800;

const double CAMERA_PAN_SPEED = 50.0;
const double CAMERA_ZOOM_SPEED = 1.05;

class InputHandler {
private:
    const unsigned char* keyboard_state;
    unsigned int mouse_state;
    int mouse_pos_x;
    int mouse_pos_y;

    void get_input_poll(Gamestate&);
    void get_input_camera();
    void get_input_mouse(Gamestate&);

public:
    InputHandler();
    InputHandler(const InputHandler&) = delete;

    bool quit;
    double camera_x;
    double camera_y;
    double zoom;
    Cell highlighted_cell;

    void get_input(Gamestate&);
};

#endif
```

**input.cpp**

```
#include "input.h"

#include <cmath>

InputHandler::InputHandler() :
    quit(false),
    camera_x(0),
    camera_y(0),
    zoom(60) {
    keyboard_state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    mouse_state = SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_pos_x, &mouse_pos_y);
}

void InputHandler::get_input(Gamestate& gamestate) {
    get_input_poll(gamestate);
    get_input_camera();
    get_input_mouse(gamestate);
}

void InputHandler::get_input_poll(Gamestate& gamestate) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            quit = true;
            return;
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN and event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE) {
            gamestate.paused = not gamestate.paused;
        }
    }
}

void InputHandler::get_input_camera() {
    if (keyboard_state[SDL_SCANCODE_W]) {
        camera_y -= CAMERA_PAN_SPEED;
    }
    if (keyboard_state[SDL_SCANCODE_A]) {
        camera_x -= CAMERA_PAN_SPEED;
    }
    if (keyboard_state[SDL_SCANCODE_S]) {
        camera_y += CAMERA_PAN_SPEED;
    }
    if (keyboard_state[SDL_SCANCODE_D]) {
        camera_x += CAMERA_PAN_SPEED;
    }
    if (keyboard_state[SDL_SCANCODE_Q]) {
        zoom *= CAMERA_ZOOM_SPEED;
    }
    if (keyboard_state[SDL_SCANCODE_E]) {
        zoom /= CAMERA_ZOOM_SPEED;
    }
}

void InputHandler::get_input_mouse(Gamestate& gamestate) {
    mouse_state = SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_pos_x, &mouse_pos_y);
    highlighted_cell = {(int)floor((mouse_pos_x + camera_x) / zoom),
                        (int)floor((mouse_pos_y + camera_y) / zoom)};
    if (mouse_state & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)) {
        gamestate.board.insert(highlighted_cell);
    }
    if (mouse_state & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)) {
        gamestate.board.erase(highlighted_cell);
    }
}
```

Finally `graphics.cpp` and its header render the two previous classes to the screen:

**graphics.h**

```
#ifndef _graphics_h_included_
#define _graphics_h_included_

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "input.h"
#include "logic.h"

class Graphics {
private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

public:
    Graphics();
    Graphics(const Graphics&) = delete;
    ~Graphics();

    void render(const Gamestate&, const InputHandler&) const;
};

#endif
```

**graphics.cpp**

```
#include "graphics.h"

#include <cmath>

Graphics::Graphics() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("dungeon", 0, 0, WINDOW_SIZE_X, WINDOW_SIZE_Y, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
}

Graphics::~Graphics() {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Graphics::render(const Gamestate& gamestate, const InputHandler& i) const {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_Rect destination;
    // Draw board
    for (Cell c : gamestate.board) {
        destination = {(int)(c.x * i.zoom - i.camera_x), (int)(c.y * i.zoom - i.camera_y),
                       (int)ceil(i.zoom), (int)ceil(i.zoom)};
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &destination);
    }
    // Highlight cell under mouse
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 128);
    Cell c = i.highlighted_cell;
    destination = {(int)(c.x * i.zoom - i.camera_x), (int)(c.y * i.zoom - i.camera_y),
                   (int)ceil(i.zoom), (int)ceil(i.zoom)};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &destination);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: In C++ generators are way more complex than in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059187/equivalent-c-to-python-generator-pattern

Comment: Not a *code*review but you should document the avaible commands more. See my pull request for example documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Avoid object creation

The SDL library does a *lot* of memory allocation and deallocation which tends to slow things down a bit.  You can avoid that problem by using references in several of your "range for" loops.  For example, in `Gamestate::update()` you could use this:

```
// Count neighbours of each cell
for (const Cell &c : board) {
    for (Cell &n : c.get_neighbours()) {
```

By using references, you avoid the `Cell` construction/deletion that would otherwise occur.

### Reuse objects where practical

Instead of creating a new `Cell` inside `InputHandler::get_input_mouse` each time, why not just update the one that already exists?  For convenience, you could create this `Cell` member function:

```
void setPos(int xval, int yval) { x=xval; y=yval; }
```

And alter the line within `get_input_mouse` to use it instead of doing yet another `Cell` creation/destruction cycle:

```
highlighted_cell.setPos((int)floor((mouse_pos_x + camera_x) / zoom),
                    (int)floor((mouse_pos_y + camera_y) / zoom));
```

### Rethink `get_neighbours`

You're right to question whether the current method is efficient.  It's not particularly, because it requires the creation and destruction of many objects (the `std::vector` and each of the `Cell`s within it) each time it's called.  This is also true of the `num_neighbors` map.

A small improvement might be to define a `neighbours` array which can be constructed once and reused:

```
static const std::array<Cell, 9> neighbours{{ 
    {-1, -1}, { 0, -1}, {+1, -1},
    {-1,  0}, { 0,  0}, {+1,  0},
    {-1, +1}, { 0, +1}, {+1, +1} 
}};
```

Then the cell counting would look like this:

```
for (Cell n : neighbours) {
    n += c;
    if (!num_neighbours.count(n)) {
        num_neighbours.emplace(n, 0);
    }
    ++num_neighbours[n];    // Note each cell counts itself as a neighbour
}
```

In this version, it still creates a new `Cell` for each iteration (note that this version of the loop is not using a reference) but at least the `std::vector` is not being created/destroyed each call.

The `map` could also be made `static` and then simply `clear()` it each iteration instead of incurring the construct/destroy overhead.

### Provide a "zoom extents" function

In the case of a prolific colony, it may not be easy to see the whole thing on screen.  One feature enhancement might be to calculate a bounding box for all cells in the board and zoom to that if some particular key is pressed.

### Change the name of the window

I was somewhat surprised to see this window titled "dungeon"!  I assume that was a cut-and-paste from some other program, but it probably should be changed.

Comment: I also meant to mention that yes, your three input routines are good design in my view.  Nice clean separation making it easy to understand where things are done.